# RoR, link not redirecting to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using RoR 4 with ruby 2 with Devise implemented.
I can't seem to get a link on my users page to redirect to the users stats_path.
Here's the code.

pages_controller

```
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def opening
    end

    def user
    end

    def stats
    end
   end
```

routes.rb

```
    devise_for :users
    root "pages#opening"
    get "user" => "pages#user"
    get "stats" => "pages#stats"
```

On the profile page, the link is written as follows.

```
  <div class="profile-bar"> 
   <h1 style="position: relative; color:white"> <%= current_user.first_name %></h1>


   <%=link_to "Your Settings", stats_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
  </div>
```

The link won't redirect the user to their stats page, which is weird because it was working last night, and I don't remember changing anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's a link to the github page - https://github.com/Thefoodie/PupPics

Update: So apparently I haven't set my code up to where each user has a stats page. I guess I should stop coding so late at night. I'd appreciate any help setting it up to where each user has a stats page, since I'm still new to coding.

Comment: Any more info of what exactly happens would be appreciated.

Comment: The button doesn't click. The link itself doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: This worked last night, and I can't seem to find what the problem is.

Comment: https://github.com/Thefoodie/PupPics/blob/master/app/views/pages/user.html.erb it's in there

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'age': during migration, giving up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of issues causing the problem:

1. Routes
2. Controller Action
3. HTML / CSS Rendering

---

**Routes**

Your routes should be structured like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users
root "pages#opening"
resources :pages, only: [] do
    collection do
        get :user
        get :stats
    end
end
```

You should post the results of `rake routes` in your cmd to give us an idea of what routes your app has

---

**Controller**

To clarify, it seems your controller code is OK but we need to know any logs for when it loads. Here's a correctly formatted controller layout for you:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def opening
    end

    def user
    end

    def stats
    end
end
```

---

**HTML / CSS**

My hunch is your HTML / CSS is not rendering the link correctly

Firstly, you're using [inline styling](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) (bad):

```
<h1 style="position: relative; color:white">
```

Secondly, you're using a class on your link:

```
<%=link_to "Your Settings", stats_path %>
```

Try removing the class & using the stats_path which was presented in the `rake routes` operation

Comment: I changed my user page to what it was before I started coding tonight, and it works again. It's definitely something on that page, I just have to figure out what.

Comment: Can you post the page code again? I'll be able to see what's up

Comment: You removed the `class` from your `stats_path` link (just like I recommended). To see why it works, you should look at the other answer :) It's a styling issue with BootStrap

Comment: I'm also now concerned that I my stats page, which is really just an edit page, isn't working properly. I basically copied and pasted the devise edit form into a new page - and it works - but I can't seem to update anything, I just get a notice that "No route matches [PATCH] "/user"" I need to do more digging!

Comment: You need to read up on [`RESTful routing`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). You'll need an "update" method to save the edited data to your db

Answer (score 1):

This is a css/html issue :
In your user.html.erb view, remove this div `<div style="position: relative; top: -350px">` and after that you can click on your link.

You need to use bootstrap grid instead of trying to move your dom elements with position attributes.